# sentence extraction in pdftron

Tags: pdftron

I want to highlight sentence on mouse hover on each word of that sentence in pdf document, i tried some way but i couldn't achieve this goal.

Is there any way to do this with pdftron?

I want to complete this event handler:

```
            WebViewer({
                path: '/assets/plugins/pdftron',
                initialDoc: '/practical.pdf',
                fullAPI: true,
                disableLogs: true
            }, document.getElementById('pdf'))
                .then((instance) => {
                    const { PDFNet, docViewer } = instance;

                    const Tools = instance.Tools;

                    docViewer.on('mouseMove', (e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
                    
                });
```

Comment: To confirm you want to select the entire sentence and not just a specific word? It may be a bit simpler to get a specific word but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use text extractor to get the text from the page and then iterate over it to find which part corresponds to the position of the mouse https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/extraction/text-extract/#advanced-text-extraction-from-a-page-region

You'll probably need to convert the mouse coordinates to window coordinates https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates/#converting-between-mouse-locations-and-window-coordinates, window coordinates to page coordinates https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates/#converting-between-window-and-viewer-page-coordinates and finally page coordinates to PDF page coordinates https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/coordinates/#converting-between-pdf-and-viewer-coordinates to compare with the values from text extractor